# How do I run multiple setIntervals efficiently?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am creating a bot where every 24 I retrieve categories from a database, and for each category, I will send a post while each post is separated by 1 hour. (After 24 hours send the first post and then one hour later send the next, etc)

My question is how would I set this up while still being able to stop a certain category for the next day. I know setIntervals have an id and I can add them to an array and I can stop the interval with this id. However, I feel like this isn't the most ideal solution.

This is my current solution however I feel like this can be done better either with a node.js package or some other clever work.

```
let intervalIds = [];
let interval = [];
const categories = ["sad", "toebeans", "meow"]
console.log(`${interval.length}`);

categories.forEach(category => {
    let id = interval.push(setInterval(() => {console.log(`Interval for ${category}`)}, 6000000000));
    intervalIds.push(`${category}=${id}`)
});
// clearInterval(interval[2]) STOPS 6
console.log(interval);
console.log(intervalIds);

let a = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < intervalIds.length; i++) {
    let split = intervalIds[i].split("=");
    if (split[0] === "sad") {
        clear(a);
        break;
    }
    a++;
}

function clear(a) {
  clearInterval(interval[a]);
  console.log(interval);
}
```

I want to be able to call one command that starts all of the timers, and another command that allows a single category to either be turned on or off.

Thanks in advance for the help guys.

Comment: The `setInterval` is just to "wake you up".  What you do in that moment once you're awake is up to you.  You could check all your categories with a single interval timer.  You could selectively decide whether each category needs to be updated.  Also, there's nothing particularly wrong with using multiple timers.  So can you please elaborate on _"However, I feel like this isn't the most ideal solution."_  and _"I feel like this can be done better"_ Why do you feel like that?

Comment: I feel like having multiple setIntervals running would start to create problems with performance if there ends up being 20+ categories. However I don't know how to stagger each category post by 1 hour with only using one setInterval so I was trying to find a solution.

Comment: What if you have 400 categories?  How do you want to stagger the categories if there are more categories than there are hours in a day?  Basically set an hourly callback, and schedule each category into one of the least used callback time slots.  Even in the worst case, it sounds like you would only have 24 timers at most.  So why not just have one hourly timer?

Comment: there's no reason to have an interval per category.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
let curPost = 0;
const CategoryTimer = setInterval(() => {
  // Database Call
  let categories = ["sad", "toebeans", "meows", "tucked", "smol", "chonky"];
  
  // Make post
  console.log(`Post for ${categories[curPost]}`);

  if (curPost === categories.length - 1) {
    curPost = -1;
    console.log("Restart!");
  }

  curPost++;
}, 1000000;
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
const myThings = ['thing1', 'thing2', 'thing3'];

function runThings(things, msBetweenThings) {
  let nextThingIndex = 0;
  console.log('running things');
  const myInterval = setInterval(() => {
    if (nextThingIndex >= 0) {
      console.log(things[nextThingIndex++]);
      if (nextThingIndex >= myThings.length) {
        console.log('ran out of things!')
        clearInterval(myInterval);  // cleanup when done
      }
    }
  }, msBetweenThings);
}
// start it up by sending a list of things and a delay
runThings(myThings, 10000)
```

Answer (score -1):

better sollution would be make one interval, and in this interval iterate over all categories. Then you can 'set' category as active or inactive:

```js
let categories = new Map();
categories.set("sad", true);
categories.set("toebeans", true);
categories.set("moew", true);

setInterval(() => {
  Array.from(categories.keys()).forEach((category) => {
    if (categories.get(category)) console.log(`Interval for ${category}`);
    //console.log(categories);
  });
}, 6000000000);

function setActive(category, isActive) {
  categories.set(category, isActive);
}

//disable some category
setActive("sad", false);
```

Comment: This looks good, but how would I be able to stagger each post for each category by 1 hour?

Comment: Sorry, just copied interval value from you. My mistake. This should be hourly interval, not daily. In separate daily interval just fetch new categories and rebuild categories Map.

Answer (score -1):

Make a javascript class that let's you register the category of command by sending a function (the command), a string (the category), and an interval.

```
myClass.register("some-category", 60000, function(){ doWork(); });
```

The class will need to maintain each category in a separate array. I would make an object of arrays since they can be referenced via string. E.g.

```
categories["some-category"].push(command);
```

Now that you have a registration tool and a way to store the commands sorted. Add a few methods to your javascript class for starting and stopping these:

```
startAll();
stopAll();
startCategory("some-category");
stopCategory("some-category");
```

Here is an example **registration** method:

```
function register(category, interval, callback) {
    if(!this.categories[category]) this.categories[category] = [];
    let token = setInterval(callback, interval);
    this.categories[category].push({token:token, callback:callback});
}
```

Here is an example **stopCategory** method:

```
function stopCategory(category) {
    if(this.categories[category]) {
       for(let i=0; i<this.categories[category].length; i++) {
          clearInterval(this.categories[category][i].token);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello thank you for your response, can you please help me with the methods? I know how to make the class and register new categories to it but how can I make a method to stop them? With just ```clearInterval(categories["some-category"])```?

Comment: I added the methods you needed help with.